# How to include webview in existing Qt project?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, include, qt6

I am trying to include one of the following libraries:

```
#include <QtWebView>
#include <QWebView>
#include <QtWebEngineWidgets>
#include <WebEngineCore>
#include <QtWebEngine>
```

Each time I add one of its includes an error appears in my code. However, I use Qt 6.3.1 and I find files that correspond to the includes in my system installation folder under macOS. I use a cmake in my qt project and not a file.pro or qmake.

Ultimately, I want to display a web form in my UI.

Comment: Qt migrated from `QWebView` to `QWebEngineView` nowadays, so the answers below should work (once you remove your `QWebView` include, and migrate your entire logic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you install the `QtWebEngine` module when installing Qt.

[image]

Then, in your `CMakeLists.txt`, you would write something like this below.

Please note that you should use [versionless targets as recommended by the Qt Project](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/cmake-qt5-and-qt6-compatibility.html#recommended-practices), i.e. do not use `Qt6::WebEngineWidgets` as that would have portability issues.

```
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS WebEngineWidgets REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(YourTarget Qt::WebEngineWidgets)
add_executable(YourTarget main.cpp)
```

Then, you can just write something like this in your `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEngineView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QWebEngineView view;
    view.setUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("https://www.qt.io")));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Please refer to the [official examples](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebengine.git/tree/examples/webenginewidgets/webui?h=6.3) for further details.

Comment: But this relies on a QtWebEngineProcess which is basically not working after signing on a MacOS. IS there a way to use only QtWebView without QtWebEngineProcess ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add `WebEngineWidgets` module to your cmake file

```
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS WebEngineWidgets)
target_link_libraries(mytarget PRIVATE Qt6::WebEngineWidgets)
```

then `#include <QWebEngineView>`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebengineview.html